# Survival function estimate for coxph

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am currently wondering which estimator for the survival function is used for coxph objects from the survival package.
It is clear, that $\hat{S}(t|x) = \hat{S}_0(t)^{\text{exp}(\hat{\beta}^Tx)}$, but what does the package use for $\hat{S}_0(t)$? Is it $\hat{S}_0(t) = \text{exp}(-\sum_{t_i \leq T} \frac{1}{\sum_{j\in R(t_i)}\text{exp}(\hat{\beta}^T x_{(j)})})$(Thats due to Breslow I think). I sadly couldn't find any information regarding this.

Comment: The R `survival` package by Terry Therneau is one of the best documented of all 20,000 R packages.  Please spend more time reading the extensive documentation, which is extended by the vignettes that come with the package.

Comment: @bubblegum174 - It is the Breslow estimate, there is a very well writen guide here which goes into detail: https://missingdatasolutions.rbind.io/2022/12/cox-baseline-hazard/